# Animate Same Activity

Tags: android, android-listview, listactivity

Is it possible to animate the same activity without actually reloading the activity instance?

I would like to make my ListActivity slide aside and reveal itself again but with new data in the ListView. This will occur each time the user drills down the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ViewAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html) should solve your problem.